# Hold down label value increment button in Swift 3 on xcode 8.3.3

Tags: swift, button

I have a simple app which does some probability calculations. I have a plus button which increments a label value 0.1% at a time. What I want to do is increment it faster if I hold down the plus button. All the code I've searched for is for older versions of Swift or Xcode and I can't get my head around how to do it!

At the moment, I have returned to a functioning app with an `@IBAction` func called `plusButton` which just adds 0.1% to a label `@IBOutlet` called `preAssessmentProbability`.

I would be most grateful if anyone could help with telling me how to keep this functionality but add the ability to hold down the `plusButton` to increment the `preAssessmentProbability` label more rapidly (bonus gratitude if you can help with telling me how to set the rate of this).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235903/press-and-hold-button-for-repeat-fire) question that might help, but unfortunately uses an older version of swift. You can, however check it out to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Xcoder; I did see this one and figured it was doing more than I wanted it to but I can try to implement it and see if it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation. First, make sure that you connect the three actions of your button in this way.[image]

Then your code should look like

```
@IBAction func buttonUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
    self.buttonUp()
}

@IBAction func buttonUpOutside(_ sender: Any) {
    self.buttonUp()
}

@IBAction func buttonTouchDown(_ sender: Any) {
    self.buttonDown()
}

func buttonDown() {
    increaseSpeed()
    holdTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector:#selector(increaseSpeed), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func buttonUp() {
    speed = 1.0
    holdTimer.invalidate()
    addPercentTimer.invalidate()
}

func increaseSpeed(){
    if speed != 1 {
        addPercentTimer.invalidate()
    }
    if speed > 0 {
        speed -= 0.2 //make it faster!
    }
    addPercentTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: speed, target: self, selector:#selector(addPercent), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func addPercent(){
    preAssessmentProbability += 0.1
}
```

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately, I have not been able to get this to run. I have declared holdTimer and addPercentTimer as Timer() objects. I have also created an IBOutlet for the plusButton (I don't know if this is required). I have also amended the addPercent() function as preAssessmentProbability is a Label. After all that, I'm only getting one error which is in regard to you first line: plusButton.addTarget ... for: .touchDown. That error is "Declaration Expected" which confuses me! I assumed it was declared in the IBAction or IBOutlet! Can you give me any pointers?! Thanks +++

Comment: @RichardHaydon  Hey. My methods are for adding button listeners. You are using IBActions? Meaning storyboard connections? If so I can update my answer for that

Comment: @ FangminNing - yes, I'm using IBActions. I actually don't know what a button listener is, so I will look that up! I have only been coding since Monday! Would a button listener be better? If you could give me the solution for IBActions, though, it'd probably be easier for me. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @RichardHaydon Sorry, forget about listener, I am talking about IBAction. So IBAction is a connection made between storyboard action and the code. On the other hand, add target is a programmatically way of getting button click action. Let me update my answer to do storyboard IBAction

Comment: Thanks @Fangming-Ning! I've added a single increment to TouchUpInside so it has original functionality. The only problem is that it now crashes after 18 increments at a timeInterval of 2 seconds and after 8 increments at a timeInterval of 1 second. I'm wondering if that has anything to do with the speed increase? You've got me much further than I ever did myself!!!

Comment: @RichardHaydon  no problem. Don't forget to mark it as correct answer. Happy coding :)