# Continuosly call a function with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, material-design

do you know a way to continuously call a function from a UIBarButtonItem in MDC if the button is kept pressed and then call it once if pressed once? Like a fwd/play behaviour.

UPDATE: I am not using the Storyboard

My button

```
let ffwButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fwd"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(clickfwd))
```

Thanks.

Comment: See this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235903/press-and-hold-button-for-repeat-fire

Comment: You should use UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using the Storyboard. Updating the question.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058082/swift-long-press-gesture-recognizer-detect-taps-and-long-press?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @czane How is the lack of a storyboard relevant to your question or the links you are being given?

Answer (score 1):

A `UIBarButtonItem` does not quite work like a `UIButton` because it doesn't inherit from `UIControl`. It has only one target and one action. UIButtons on the other hand inherit from `UIControl`; therefore you can add target/action pairs for all sorts of interesting control events, including `.touchDown` and `.touchUpInside`.

Using a `UIButton` you could start a timer upon `.touchDown` that sends events repeatedly and invalidate it upon `.touchUpInside`.

Since you need a `UIBarButtonItem`, have a look at its `init(customView: UIView)` initialiser. It lets you create a `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIButton` inside.

Comment: Perfect nils, thanks!