# How create target for UIButton with long-time press(repeating handler)?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I try to create UIButton, which will increase some variable with long-pressing. So, when user touch button for long time increasing handler repeats.

I have something like this:

**Swift 4.0**

```
@IBOutlet var increaseButton: UIButton!
var someVariable = 0

...

increaseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increase(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

...

@IBAction func increase(sender: UIButton) {
    someVariable += 1
}
```

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34235903/1630618).

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of three different control events for button mainly,

```
.touchDown
.touchUpOutside
.touchUpInside
```

And track the time between touchDown and any touchup events to change your handler time.

Comment: But to handle events user need to remove finger from button, or no?